# Get SP Configuration Database Version in C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm looking to grab the SharePoint Configuration Database version via C# and found the [SPConfigDatabase class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms462618) under [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms463219) which has a `Version` member. This is exactly what I'm looking for, but this is now obsolete.

What is the best method for doing this? Ideally I'd like to grab the Cumulative Update date as well, though this is essentially just another name for the version number.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to get it using C# is to use the [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfarm.aspx) class and the property you are looking for is [BuildVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfarm.buildversion):

```
var v = SPFarm.Local.BuildVersion;
```

As that returns a [System.Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/hdxyt63s) object, you may want to concatenate the values together to make the string appear as it does in the central admin:

```
var friendly = v.Major + "." + v.Minor + "." + v.Build + "." + v.Revision;
```

Also, please note that to access the SPFarm.Local property, you will need to be running the code in 64-bit mode as well as have an authorized account. In fact, with the UAC enabled on my VM I needed to run my code by right-clicking on it and choosing "Run as Administrator" as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found a tentative solution by executing a powershell script. Here's my solution that prints out the result to the console from the powershell script:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
.
.
.
MAIN CODE:
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

runspace.Open();


PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript("Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell");
ps.AddScript("get-spfarm | select BuildVersion");
ps.AddCommand("Out-String");

Collection <PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
runspace.Close();

foreach (PSObject obj in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
}
```

Credit to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C
and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu/sharepoint2010general/thread/88b11fe3-c218-49a3-ac4b-d1a04939980c

Answer (score 0):

just connect to the database and execute this query

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion'), 
       SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), 
       SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
```

references:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185

I hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this is not what I'm looking for. This gets the version of SQL Server Management Studio, but not my SP Config Database version. You can see what I'm referring to by going to SharePoint Central Admin > Servers in Farm > Configuration database version.

Comment: You can use SQL Server Profiler to find out the SQL query used when you open that page. Then take the same approach and answer your own question :)